# Segfault: rosrun collada_urdf urdf_to_collada

Tags: ros, urdf, collada-urdf, collada, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been working with OpenRave to get their IKFast IK solver to work, and I have been using the [urdf_to_collada](http://www.ros.org/wiki/collada_urdf) tool to convert my urdf to dae format. However, with the upgrade to Groovy this tool now seg faults. All it says is:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I tested this with both my custom urdf and the standard pr2.urdf. Having this tool back would be really nice!

**Update** the gdb backtrace:

```
urdf_openrave:gdb --args /opt/ros/groovy/lib/collada_urdf/urdf_to_collada clam.urdf clam.dae
Reading symbols from /opt/ros/groovy/lib/collada_urdf/urdf_to_collada...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /opt/ros/groovy/lib/collada_urdf/urdf_to_collada clam.urdf clam.dae
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
 WARN ros.collada_urdf: failed to load resource /home/dave/ros/clam/src/clam_description/stl/base_link.STL
 ...
 WARN ros.collada_urdf: failed to load resource /home/dave/ros/clam/src/clam_description/stl/tabletop_link.STL

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6d5ef28 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6d5ef28 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff55b7300 in cdom::nativePathToUri(std::string const&, cdom::systemType) ()
   from /usr/lib/libcollada-dom2.4-dp.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff55a8bd0 in DAE::makeFullUri(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/libcollada-dom2.4-dp.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff55a92d6 in DAE::writeCommon(std::string const&, std::string const&, bool) ()
   from /usr/lib/libcollada-dom2.4-dp.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff7b95379 in collada_urdf::colladaToFile(boost::shared_ptr<DAE>, std::string const&) ()
   from /opt/ros/groovy/lib/libcollada_urdf.so
#5  0x0000000000402173 in main ()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51504/segfault:-rosrun-collada_urdf-urdf_to_collada/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Still experiencing this in Hydro. The issue is tracked on GitHub here: https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues/4

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0